# Selenium WebDriver C#, Unable to Enter value in a textbox

Tags: c#, selenium

How do i identify the text box and place a value in the text box ?

**Code Snippet**

```
<div id="CTR_StartDate" class=" datePickerXtreme datePickerContainer datePickerXtreme datePickerContainer datePickerXtreme datePickerContainer">
    <input tabindex="0" name="ct100$CTR_StartDatectl00" value="Date" id="CTR_StartDate_ctl00" class="datePickerXtremeDateOnly   validField" type="text">
    <a tabindex="0" href="#" class="ui-datepicker-icon">&nbsp;</a>
    <input tabindex="0" value="Tuesday, 10 January 2017 00:00:00" name="ct100$CTR_StartDatectl01" id="CTR_StartDate_ctl01" type="hidden">
    <input tabindex="0" value="Tuesday, 10 January 2017 00:00:00" name="ct100$CTR_StartDatectl02" id="CTR_StartDate_ctl02" type="hidden">
    <span id="CTR_StartDate_ctl04" category="Common" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;"></span>
    <input tabindex="0" name="ct100$CTR_StartDatectl03" id="CTR_StartDate_ctl03" value="GMT Standard Time" type="hidden">
</div>
```

Below is the code that i am using to place the text:

```
IWebElement ContractStartDate = driver.FindElement(By.Id("CTR_StartDate_ctl00"));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("CTR_StartDate_ctl00")));
ContractStartDate.SendKeys("14/07/2016");
```

I have tried it with Name, it still doesn't work. Few times it does work. Thats very rare though. I have tried clicking on the text box and placing the value using send keys, still doesn't work. Sometimes strange exceptions occur.

Can someone help me with this please ?

Comment: Please share strange exceptions which is occur as well...

Comment: May be your name or id is looks like dynamic generated....

Comment: try once with this `xpath` and let me know.. `//div[@id = 'CTR_StartDate']/input[contains(@class,'datePickerXtremeDateOnly')]`

Comment: or this `cssSelector`....`div#CTR_StartDate > input.datePickerXtremeDateOnly`

Comment: what's the framework the application is built on?Is it possible to provide the link to the application

Comment: interesting set of input siblings here.  Something complicated is probably going on with the controls.  @Madhan had a good question...perhaps there's something unique about the application's framework that is relevant here.

Comment: Guys - 

I will not be able to share the application with you guys. Apologies for that.

Name / Id - I dont think they are dynamically generated, As far as i have seen, it always remained the same.

Framework - DotNet Framework 3.5

I hope this response has all the information.

Comment: When it doesn't work, what happens? What errors are you getting, etc.?

Comment: By Framework I meant the webapplication framwork[angular-js,bootstrap etc)

Answer (score 1):

can you try and use a Css selector?

```
String selector = "div.datePickerXtreme input.datePickerXtremeDateOnly";
IWebElement ContractStartDate = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(selector));
ContractStartDate.Clear();
ContractStartDate.SendKeys("14/07/2016");
```

Comment: nope, didn't work.

No Error, But did not fill any values in the textbox either.

Answer (score 0):

May be your problem is that you are going to find element first then check it's visibility and then use `.sendKeys()` on already found `element` which may be visible or not stored alraedy into  `ContractStartDate` that's why your test case sometime pass and some time fail. Try as below :-

```
IWebElement ContractStartDate = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("CTR_StartDate_ctl00")));
ContractStartDate.Click();
ContractStartDate.SendKeys("14/07/2016");
```

Hope it will work...:)

Comment: I wish you were sitting next to me to have this sorted out, But anyways - your email id ?

Comment: dont you have your personal email id ?

Comment: @Sathish  try once `ContractStartDate.Click();ContractStartDate.SendKeys("14/07/2016");`..may it will work